# Populating a textbox using Ajax and Servlet

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to get a value from a Servlet to an input box of a JSP using Ajax. I have managed to get that value to an Alert box. But it didn't work when I tried to get that value into an input box. Please see the following code.

This is the ajaxtTestServlet

```
  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
   {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String text = "some text";
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    response.getWriter().write(text);
}
```

There is where the input box with the id "firstName" is.

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-

hidden="true">&times;</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal"> <img src="images/arrow-back-512.png"  width="30px" height="30px"> <small>Back</small></a> <span id="myModalLabel" style="margin-left:20px;"><font size="+2"><b>Edit New Member</b></font></span> </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="EditOnlySrvlt?idEmployee=<%=request.getParameter("idEmployee")%>"" >
          <fieldset id="modal_form">

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">First Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text"  class="form-control input-md" >
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Middle Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  name="middleName" type="text" class="form-control input-md"> 
              </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Last Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  name="lastName" type="text" class="form-control input-md"> 
              </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Date Of Birth</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  name="dateOfBirth" type="date" class="form-control input-md"> 
              </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Passport Number</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  name="passportNumber" type="text" class="form-control input-md"> 
              </div>

            </div>



      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
                </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- /Edit Job modal -->
```

this is the Script

```
 <script>
 $(function() {
//twitter bootstrap script
 $("tr#somebutton").click(function(){

 $.get("ajaxTestSrvlt", function(responseText) { // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response text...
     $('#firstName').text(responseText) ;       // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somediv" and set its text content with the response text.
});

});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's a input, you should give

```
$('#firstName').val(responseText);
```

Comment: try $('#firstName').val(JSON.stringify(responseText));

Comment: try alert("Hi") inside the click function, i think you've an error on executing click fn